# Resetting old MacBook Air to factory defaults

Tags: macbook-pro

I got an old MacBook Air. I know very little about it, because I got it as a workstation in a new job and nobody has any info about it.

I'm also a Mac newbie. These are the specs: it's running Snow Leopard, it has 128GB SSD, Core 2 Duo 1,86 GHz CPU and 2GB RAM.

I'm trying to factory reset it but don't know how.

Which MacBook edition is it? 2010 or 2011? How do I factory reset it? There is no USB in the box, just some CDs (and the computer doesn't even have an optical drive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest manner would be to use the Air's [Remote Disc functionality](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5287) to re-install the OS using an [erase and install](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3263).

Comment: if that is the simplest way, I don't know if I want to hear more complex ones... :/

Comment: I suppose you could pay to upgrade to Lion or later and use the Recovery HD to self-wipe the machine. That would be less steps. Target mode is easiest, but you'll need another Mac to do the reinstall. Lots of ways to skin this cat. :)

Comment: Note that if the MacBook is *really* old (4 years or more), resetting it this way [can brick it](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271982/problems-with-resetting-and-old-mbp-an-error-occurred-during-installation).

Comment: @FranklinYu have you seen a machine that doesn’t work when you bring a USB installer to it? If so, what build and os installer version?

Comment: Yes, I failed to install macOS High Sierra on 2010 Mac mini (should be similar to MacBook AFAIK) with bootable USB.

Comment: We suspect that Apple closed verification for Mac mini 2010, but we are still doing experiments.